# Show $a^{\frac{h}{2}}\equiv -1\pmod{p}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove if $a$ belongs to $h$ modulo $p$ and $h$ is even then $a^{\frac{h}{2}}\equiv -1\pmod{p}$

For $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $a$ belonging to $h\pmod{p}$ this means that $h$ is the least positive integer with $a^h\equiv 1\pmod{p}$

I feel that this is close to what I need to show, but have no idea what to do next, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are being told  $a^\frac{h}{2}\not \equiv  1 \bmod p$ and $(a^{\frac{h}{2}})^2\equiv1 \bmod p$.

Which are the elements that give $1\bmod p$ when squared?

$a^2\equiv 1\implies p|a^2-1=(a+1)(a-1) \overbrace{\implies}^{\text{by Euclid}} p|(a+1)$ or $p|(a-1)\implies a\equiv 1$ or $a\equiv -1$

Comment: Where are we told $a^{\frac{h}{2}}\not\equiv 1\pmod{p}$?

Comment: When we are told h is the smallest positive integer such that $a^h\equiv 1$